# Mlkit is throwing an exception when trying to build in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-mlkit

I have added mlkit to my flutter project and it is throwing an exception when building. The dart file and pubspec.yaml files do not seem to have any errors.

I tried to change some stuff in the build.gradle files however that didn't work so I reverted them back to their original state

The dart code looks like this:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

import 'package:firebase_ml_vision/firebase_ml_vision.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:mlkit/mlkit.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Facial Recognition'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  File _imageFile;
  List<Face> _faces;
  List<VisionLabel> _currentLabels = <VisionLabel>[];
  bool isLoading = false;
  ui.Image _image;

  _getImageAndDetectFacesAndObjects() async {
    final imageFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    final image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromFile(imageFile);
    FirebaseVisionLabelDetector detector = FirebaseVisionLabelDetector.instance;
    final faceDetector = FirebaseVision.instance.faceDetector();
    List<Face> faces = await faceDetector.processImage(image);
    List<VisionLabel> currentLabels =
        await detector.detectFromBinary(imageFile?.readAsBytesSync());

    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        _imageFile = imageFile;
        _faces = faces;
        _currentLabels = currentLabels;
        _loadImage(imageFile);
      });
    }
  }

  _loadImage(File file) async {
    final data = await file.readAsBytes();
    await decodeImageFromList(data).then(
      (value) => setState(() {
        _image = value;
        isLoading = false;
      }),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: isLoading
          ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : (_imageFile == null)
              ? Center(child: Text('No image selected'))
              : Center(
                  child: FittedBox(
                      child: new Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(
                        width: _image.width.toDouble(),
                        height: _image.height.toDouble(),
                        child: CustomPaint(
                          painter: FacePainter(_image, _faces),
                        ),
                      ),
                      _buildList(_currentLabels)
                    ],
                  )),
                ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _getImageAndDetectFacesAndObjects,
        tooltip: 'Take Picture',
        child: Icon(Icons.add_a_photo),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }

  Widget _buildList(List<VisionLabel> labels) {
    if (labels == null || labels.length == 0) {
      return new Text('Empty Image', textAlign: TextAlign.center);
    } else {
      return new Expanded(
          child: new Container(
        child: new ListView.builder(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
            itemCount: labels.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, i) {
              return _buildRow(
                  labels[i].label, labels[i].confidence.toString());
            }),
      ));
    }
  }

  Widget _buildRow(String label, String confidence) {
    return new ListTile(
      title: new Text(
        "\nLabel: $label \nConfidence: $confidence \n",
      ),
      dense: true,
    );
  }
}

class FacePainter extends CustomPainter {
  final ui.Image image;
  final List<Face> faces;
  final List<Rect> rects = [];

  FacePainter(this.image, this.faces) {
    for (var i = 0; i < faces.length; i++) {
      rects.add(faces[i].boundingBox);
    }
  }

  @override
  void paint(ui.Canvas canvas, ui.Size size) {
    final Paint paint = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 15.0
      ..color = Colors.amber;

    canvas.drawImage(image, Offset.zero, Paint());
    for (var i = 0; i < faces.length; i++) {
      canvas.drawRect(rects[i], paint);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(FacePainter oldDelegate) {
    return image != oldDelegate.image || faces != oldDelegate.faces;
  }
}
```

The app level build.gradle file looks like this:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.facial_app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-face-model:18.0.0'

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:23.0.0'
    // If you want to detect face contours (landmark detection and classification
    // don't require this additional model):
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-face-model:18.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The project level build.gradle looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }

    subprojects {
        project.configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
                if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.core'
                        && !details.requested.name.contains('androidx') ) {
                    details.useVersion "1.0.1"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

The error thrown is this:

```
D8: Type com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzop is referenced as an interface from `com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzpu`.
D8: Type com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzny is referenced as an interface from `com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzpy`.
D8: Type com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzny is referenced as an interface from `com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzpv`.
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\jetified-firebase-ml-model-interpreter-19.0.0.aar\b00f4f536c45683495ade7150f92c485\jars\classes.jar
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:593)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:677)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:720)
    at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForTasksWithQuickFail(WaitableExecutor.java:146)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.transform(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:405)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:239)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:235)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:230)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor660.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.LocalTaskInfoExecutor.execute(LocalTaskInfoExecutor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:277)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:262)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:135)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:200)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeWithWork(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:191)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\jetified-firebase-ml-model-interpreter-19.0.0.aar\b00f4f536c45683495ade7150f92c485\jars\classes.jar
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.launchProcessing(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:900)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.lambda$convertToDexArchive$6(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:825)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing.
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:124)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.convert(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:101)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.launchProcessing(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:895)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:65)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withD8CompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:43)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:90)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.convert(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:99)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Type com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzny is referenced as an interface from `com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzpv`.
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.failIfPendingErrors(Reporter.java:116)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.fatalError(Reporter.java:74)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:59)
    ... 10 more


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\jetified-firebase-ml-model-interpreter-19.0.0.aar\b00f4f536c45683495ade7150f92c485\jars\classes.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it just this code.

local.properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX\:MaxHeapSize\=512m -Xmx512m
```

and you should do this add this on app level build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "yourProjectPackage"
    minSdkVersion 16
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    targetSdkVersion 28

    multiDexEnabled true //important
}
```

Comment: I tried that and restarted android studio however some errors still appear

Comment: Can you edit and post your latest error you are receiving